# Asynchronous Thread.Sleep()

Tags: .net, multithreading

I want to put a delay between 2 operations without keeping busy the thread

```
 workA();
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 workB();
```

The thread must exit after workA and execute workB (maybe in a new thread) after some delay.

I wonder if it's possible some equevalent of this pseudocode

```
workA();
Thread.BeginSleep(1000, workB); // callback
```

edit
My program is in .NET 2.0

edit 2 :
System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed event will raise the event after 1000 ms. I dont know if the timer thread will be busy for 1000 ms. (so I dont gain thread economy)

Comment: Don't understand.  Your Thread.Sleep() call will put a delay between 2 operations without keeping busy the thread.  Do I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: Yes but the Threadpool for this period of time (1000 ms) will have 1 less thread available.

Comment: You might prefer `System.Threading.Timer` for this - not `System.Timers.Timer` and no - there is no "timer thread" - the wait is controlled in the OS kernel

Comment: [`MSDN: Comparing the Timer Classes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) - `System.Timers.Timer` is useful if you have a `SynchronizationContext` involved.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for the clarification

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => workB());
```

Alternatively, create a `Timer` manually.

Note this looks prettier in `async` code:

```
async Task Foo() {
    workA();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    workB();
}
```

edit: with your .NET 2.0 update, you would have to setup your own `Timer` with callback. There is a nuget package [System.Threading.Tasks](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks/3.0.1) that brings the `Task` API down to .NET 3.5, but a: it doesn't go to 2.0, and b: I don't think it includes `Task.Delay`.

Comment: or even `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();` if you don't want an async func.

Comment: @Josh you just made me cry a little. Please don't ever do that. If you're lucky it'll just be horribly inefficient. If you're unlucky: you just deadlocked a thread. It all depends on the sync context. If you want to wait synchronously: `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I don't suppose you have anywhere I could go read more about this (the why I mean)? (especially the deadlock the thread part)

Comment: For anyone interested in future `<Task>.Wait()` is actually blocking, so defeats the purpose of your asynchronous call entirely, and Marcs reasoning makes sense to me now.